# Content query webpart for show attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have added Content query webpart in home page for announcement list.

I have a done changes in XSLT file to show body field. Now I want to add attachment field.

for body i used below code:

```
<div class="Body">
     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Body" />
</div>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/344e5469-f53a-4d7d-9946-2a7f142eeb35/attachments-files-on-content-query?forum=sharepointdevelopment) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code and see if it works for you:

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
     <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
          <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

**Source**: [Attachments files on Content Query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/344e5469-f53a-4d7d-9946-2a7f142eeb35/attachments-files-on-content-query).

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: This code is for List view I believe. How can we add this in Content Query WebPart. If I use attachments field, it show 1 or 0 depending on the number of attachments to the list item.